# join on two foreign keys from same table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Not quite sure how to ask this question so if someone wants to edit to better articulate please. However I want to join on a user table however the row has two FKs from the user table

```
item_tbl
id | ownerId | lastModifiedById | itemName
------------------------------------------
1  |       1 |                2 | "Blog Post"

user_tbl
id | username
-------------
1  |     John
2  |    Sally
```

Desired output (or something like it)

```
Owner Username | last modified by |       item
----------------------------------------------
          John |            Sally | "Blog Post"
```

currently i'm doing two queries to get this information. Is there a better (read: more efficient) way?

Comment: FK's are nice, certainly, but on a select stmt, they are quite irrelevant. If I read you right. I think what you are asking is, here is my data, how do I get the desired output

Comment: You are correct that was me attempting to say ownerId and lastModifiedById are related to user_tbl.id

Comment: fair enough. And kuddo's for doing that. What you want is a double join to the user_tbl with **two** aliases. I bet ya can do it. Start by just trying to get the owner name. Then after that, you do another join to the same table (with a different alias) to pick up column 2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT user_tbl.username Owner, a.username Modifier, item_tbl.itemName 
FROM item_tbl 
JOIN user_tbl 
ON item_tbl.ownerId = user_tbl.id 
JOIN user_tbl a 
ON item_tbl.lastModifiedById = a.id;
```

worked for those curious as hinted at by Drew in comments

Comment: nice job jbh, wasn't that hard

Comment: I think you got it slightly wrong though at the very end

Comment: ahhh yesss... the awesome fail copy when working with contrived data. thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 4):

### Schema

```
create table user_tbl
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    username varchar(50) not null
);

create table item_tbl
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    ownerId int not null,
    lastModifiedById int not null,
    itemName varchar(50) not null,
    CONSTRAINT fk_own_user FOREIGN KEY (ownerId) REFERENCES user_tbl(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_mod_user FOREIGN KEY (lastModifiedById) REFERENCES user_tbl(id)
);
insert user_tbl(username) values('John');   -- this becomes id 1
insert user_tbl(username) values('Sally');  -- this becomes id 2
```

Quick test for FK failure:

```
insert item_tbl(ownerId,lastModifiedById,itemName) values (9,9,'blah');
```

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails

**Failed as expected, that's a good thing, because the data was bad**

Success:

```
insert item_tbl(ownerId,lastModifiedById,itemName) values (1,2,'the Blog Post is this');
```

---

### Query

```
select u1.username,u2.username,i.itemName 
from item_tbl i 
join user_tbl u1 
on u1.id=i.ownerId 
join user_tbl u2 
on u2.id=i.lastModifiedById;
+----------+----------+-----------------------+
| username | username | itemName              |
+----------+----------+-----------------------+
| John     | Sally    | the Blog Post is this |
+----------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Always load up on Foreign Key constraints to enforce Referential Integrity. The sign of a well-designed schema is nothing left to chance and junk being put in.

Manual page on [Foreign Key Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

About all that is missing is consideration for keys (indexes) added to item_tbl for the `ownerId` and `lastModifiedById` columns to make the joins extra fast and avoid table scans