# Medoo Syntax for Join Query with Two Foreign Keys

Tags: php, medoo

I've a requirement to perform a join operation in SQL with two foreign keys on same table. The answer in below post has the SQL for my requirement.

[Join On Two Foreign Keys From Same Table In Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622252/join-on-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table-in-sql)

I am trying to convert this query into [Medoo](https://medoo.in) syntax, but I don't get the desired output. Code posted below is my latest effort which doesn't work.

```
$db -> select( "item_tbl", [ "[>]user_tbl.id" => ["ownerId", "lastModifiedById"] ], ["username", "username", "itemName"]);
```

Could somebody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've framed the Medoo Syntax myself using aliases. Below is the Medoo equivalent code for above SQL:

```
$db->select("item_tbl",["[><]user_tbl(user_tbl_a)" => ["item_tbl.ownerId" => "id"],"[><]user_tbl(user_tbl_b)" => ["item_tbl.lastModifiedById" => "id"]],["user_tbl_a.username(Owner)","user_tbl_b.username(Modifier)","itemName"]);
```