# How to join two foreign keys that reference the same table?

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to learn SQL recently for a project and I managed to create the database. However I ran into a problem when I need to create a view because I have two foreign keys (first_dose_id and second_dose_id) that references the same table (vaccine_dose). I managed to create a view that retrieves all the personal data except the the values of second_dose. I actually tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622252/join-on-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table-in-sql) but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help?

```
alter view user_view
as 
select user.user_id, user.first_name, user.last_name, user.middle_name,
    user.gender, user.phone_number, user.birthday, user.home_address,
    city.city_name, region.region_name,
    first_vaccine.vaccine_name as 'first_dose', first.vaccine_dose_date as 'first_dose_date',
    second_vaccine.vaccine_name as 'second_dose', second.vaccine_dose_date as 
    'second_dose_date'
    
    from region
    left join city on city.region_id = region.region_id
    left join user on user.city_id = city.city_id
    left join vaccine_dose as first on first.vaccine_dose_id = user.first_dose_id 
    left join vaccine_dose as second on second.vaccine_dose_id = user.second_dose_id 
    left join vaccine as first_vaccine on first.vaccine_id = first_vaccine.vaccine_id
    left join vaccine as second_vaccine on second.vaccine_id = second_vaccine.vaccine_id;
```

It's supposed to look something like this
|Info|first_dose|first_dose_date|second_dose|second_dose_date|

Comment: I'm still in a post US holiday food coma, but why is `region` the primary table? What happens if you keep your query the same but change the `from` clause to:  `from user left join city ... left join region .. left join vaccine_dose ... ` etc?

Comment: As said, I'm not that good with sql yet and I don't really know if I'm making a simple error or not. But, it says the region id is unknown in 'on clause'

Comment: Do all your cities have regions and all your users have cities?

What does your current query return? I'm guessing it's returning one row per region. And you want one row per user?  My initial guess is there's nothing wrong with your joins for the doses.... it's the joins to the region and city. To test: remove the region and city from the query and joins and simply see if you can get a list of users with their doses.

Comment: oh it looks like this when i removed city


| city_name | region_name | first_dose | first_dose_date|
| pfizer        | 2021-06-06   | Pfizer        | 2021-06-26     |

So what did i do wrong haha (Edit: I struggling with the format but ity_name is matched with pfizer and so on...)

Comment: And yes, all cities have reasons and all users have cities. The second_dose related columns still don't appear though

Comment: Unfortunately, the comments in SO is not a great place for a back-and-forth discussion. Here's what I would try. Simplify your question: remove any reference to cities and regions from both the `select` and `from` clauses so you can focus you question on the two joins with the doses (e.g. `select ... from user where left join vaccine_dose as first ... left join vaccine_dose as second`). If that doesn't work, update the question with the updated query and the actual results you're seeing OR the error that you're getting. Also if you post the schema of the tables that will help

Comment: Hello! Actually, what you made me do actually gave me an idea that something may not be right here. So I created a new view with the same code and VOILA, it works HAHAHA. Idk what went wrong but that just wasted 5 hours of my life. Anyway THANKS A BUNCH DUDE! (U actually solved my problem on my bday so thanks for saving me time HAHHA)