# postgresql query to join table date dimensions tables to average flight times

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, syntax-error, inner-join

I have this query i built using the following references:
[Join On 2 Foreign Keys In The Same Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622252/join-on-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table-in-sql)
[Work out the number of seconds between timestamps](https://pgexercises.com/questions/date/interval2.html)
And Came Up With This Query to return the average flight time in seconds:

```
SELECT dp.purpose, AVG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (timestamp dim_year2.year_text || '-' || dim_month2.month_text || '-' || dim_day2.day_text || ' ' || dim_hour2.hour_text || ':' || dim_minute2.minute_text || ':' || dim_second2.second_text - dim_year1.year_text || '-' || dim_month1.month_text || '-' || dim_day1.day_text || ' ' || dim_hour1.hour_text || ':' || dim_minute1.minute_text || ':' || dim_second1.second_text))) AS avg_flight_time
FROM public.fact_flights ff
INNER JOIN dim_year dim_year1 ON dim_year1.year = ff.start_year_id
INNER JOIN dim_month dim_month1 ON dim_month1.month = ff.start_month_id
INNER JOIN dim_day dim_day1 ON dim_day1.day = ff.start_day_id
INNER JOIN dim_hour dim_hour1 ON dim_hour1.hour = ff.start_hour_id
INNER JOIN dim_minute dim_minute1 ON dim_minute1.minute = ff.start_minute_id
INNER JOIN dim_second dim_second1 ON dim_second1.second = ff.start_second_id
INNER JOIN dim_year dim_year2 ON dim_year2.year = ff.end_year_id
INNER JOIN dim_month dim_month2 ON dim_month2.month = ff.end_month_id
INNER JOIN dim_day dim_day2 ON dim_day2.day = ff.end_day_id
INNER JOIN dim_hour dim_hour2 ON dim_hour2.hour = ff.end_hour_id
INNER JOIN dim_minute dim_minute2 ON dim_minute2.minute = ff.end_minute_id
INNER JOIN dim_second dim_second2 ON dim_second2.second = ff.end_second_id
INNER JOIN dim_purpose dp ON dp.purpose_id = ff.purpose
GROUP BY dp.purpose;
```

the tables are as follows:
fact_flights:
flight_id(id, integer),
purpose(fk dim_purpose.purpose_id),
start_year_id(fk dim_year.year),
start_month_id(fk dim_month.month),
start_day_id(fk dim_day.day),
start_hour_id(fk dim_hour.hour),
start_minute_id(fk dim_minute.minute),
start_second_id(fk dim_second.second),
end_year_id(fk dim_year),
end_month_id(fk dim_month.month),
end_day_id(fk dim_day.day),
end_hour_id(fk dim_hour.hour),
end_minute_id(fk dim_minute.minute),
end_second_id(fk dim_second.second),
ALL ARE INTEGERS, ALL ARE FOREIGN KEYS EXCEPT flight_id.
dim_year:
year(id, integer),
year_text(varchar).
dim_month:
month(id, integer),
month_text(varchar).
dim_day:
day(id, integer),
day_text(varchar).
dim_hour:
hour(id, integer),
hour_text(varchar).
dim_minute:
minute(id, integer),
minute_text(varchar).
dim_second:
second(id, integer),
second_text(varchar).
dim_purpose:
purpose_id(id, integer),
purpose(varchar).

PGSQL Gives a Syntax Error on "dim_year2" and i really don't know why...
thanks to anyone who helps

I tried casting each individual string as a timestamp and then using extract epoch, casting to varchar and then casting to timestamp, using to TO_TIMESTAMP, none worked
expected the query to return 2 column the purpose of the flight and the average flight time of all flights in that purpose category

Comment: I'd try something like `(dim_year2.year_text ||  ...)::timestamp)`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: @jarlh i tried that and it didn't work, it does return an answer but the avg_flight_time field is empty.